# Can I use ipfw on OSX 10.8 (Mountain Lion)

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion

I read that ipfw will be replaced by pf firewall. Will i still be able to use ipfw on a "standart mac" to do some filtering for my application?

Comment: Nobody can answer that question here because information on Mountain Lion is currently subject to NDA. Ask on Apple's beta developer forums.

Comment: Thanks! So i'll just wait a little...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, your old rules are converted but there is NO GUI for administrating it, you have to use the command line for that.

Apple says, it's depreciated now and you should use PF (man pfctl).